How to use "Find" function
As a test, I tried to find space using "=FIND(" ",D2)" for D2 cell written like "2017/9/1  0:02:01", but I got an error like "#VALUE!" and I cannot fix it. I would appreciete it if someone can advice, thanks.
I tired to the above code, but I couldn't get a right answer. I expected to receive the number that the space location in D2 cell.

D2 is a date - which is internally a number (42979,0014). That's why FIND doesn't find a blank. What is your basic goal using FIND?
